# GRAILS g:each problem

Tags: grails

I cant get the g:each to work. I am trying to iterate over anything but it never works = doesnt generate any html.

index.gsp

```
<g:each var="i" in="${userList}" controller="user">
          <li>Item ${i.name}</li>
</g:each>
```

userController.groovy

```
class UserController {
    ...        
        def userList = {

            User.list()

        }
        ...
}
```

Then I have User.groovy filled with number of users..

What am i supposed to write in     in="${.....}" to iterate for example over users declared as User.groovy ? I have tried : User, users, User.list() ...

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Let's say i have a

```
def findOne {

 [users : User.findAllByNameLike("%Petr%")

}
```

in my UserCotroller.

How do i use g:each for it because

```
<g:each var="user" in="${findOne}">
```

won't do anything..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example. `userList` is a Closure, so it's the action name, so I'm assuming you're accessing http://localhost:8080/appname/user/userList

If you return something from a controller action to be rendered in the GSP, it has to be in a `Map`, the "model". Each value in the map is exposed in the GSP using the map key as its name. So the controller action corresponding to your GSP would be

```
def userList = {
    [users: User.list()]
}
```

and then you can iterate with

```
<g:each var="user" in="${users}">
    <li>Item ${user.name}</li>
</g:each>
```

The name doesn't matter - it just has to be the same in the model map as in the GSP.

Comment: My index.gsp is http://localhost:8080/GrailsAppTest/, thats how my app starts. I am just trying to list users in a list on the index page, just to try it out. I understand the map: model thing but it seems it just won't access it from there.

Comment: The latter does work. Try `grails generate-all User` and see how default scaffolding works.

Comment: When I use   <g:each var="user" in="${User.list()}"> ... I get: Cannot invoke method list() on null object error

Comment: I just did the above, and checked the generated list.gsp and it had    <%@ page import="Default.User" %> on top of the page. It works now !  Thanks Victor

Comment: But how do i access a specific action/closure with g:each ? I want for example 10 different queries in my USerControler and then display them on my page.